# jsp is not iterating over Linkedhashmap sent by servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to generate table rows from LinkedHashmap sent from servlet. But whenever i execute i get empty or null map. I tried running the servlet alone to check whether the data is existing in linkedhashmap and it does. But only when i pass it to the jsp page i guess i am receiving an empty map.

Below is the code

Jsp Code:

```
<%@ page language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
</head>

<body id = body>
<form action="Servlet" method="get">        
    <title>Enter Search Item</title>
    <br>
    <%
    String val = request.getParameter( "search" );
    if ( val!= null ) {
        val = val.toString() ;
   } else {
       val ="";
    }
    %>
        Search Item: <input type="text" name = "searchTerm" value = '<%=val%>' >
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button">
</form>
<div>
    <table>
            <c:if test="${not empty Documents}">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                    <td><h2>Title</h2></td>
                     <td><h2>Overview</h2></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${Documents}" var="document">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href = ${document.key}>${document.value}</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
            </c:if>

    </table>
</div> 

</body>
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String search = request.getParameter("searchTerm");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> Docs = null;
    ASearch ad;
    try {
        ad = new ASearch();
        Docs = ad.getData(search);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setAttribute("Documents", Docs); // Docs is not empty/NULL.
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp?search="+search);

    dispatcher.forward( request, response );

}
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is perfectly fine. Just one line has to be added to the jsp file

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap` is not itself an `Iterable` type. If you want to iterate over both the keys and values, you'd need to iterate over keys in the keyset, and fetch the corresponding values.

If you're not using the type as a `Map<>`, I'd suggest using a list of pairs.

Comment: Map sent by servlet is empty when i receive on jsp. There is an if condition in jsp to check for non empty map and only then i will be able to iterate over the map.